# Color os: Phone corrupted after update

Tags: oppo-coloros

I just updated my oppo find x2 neo from android 11 to 12. However the phone tries to power on a few times, and then goes to recovery mode. Online update does not work (it says "no updates found.")

Is there a way of fixing this without losing all my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to fix it. You have to factory reset :(

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).